# how to get the elapsed time while interacting with other functions in a text-based application in python

Tags: python, input, output, text-based

So I created this project that records football (soccer) stats. Up to now it records only corner and free kicks but I want to record the possession time between the 2 teams. My main problem is that when I try to keep possession time, the other functions won't work. Here's what I've tried:

```
import time

fk_range = range(0, 1000)
fk_list = list(fk_range)
ck_range = range(0, 1000)
ck_list = list(ck_range)


def body():
    while True:
        choice = input("")
        if choice == "fk":

            first_number_fk = fk_list[0]
            fk_list.remove(first_number_fk)
            number_fk = fk_list[0]
            string_number_fk = str(number_fk)
            print("Free Kick(s)", string_number_fk)

        elif choice == "ck":

            first_number_ck = ck_list[0]
            ck_list.remove(first_number_ck)
            number_ck = ck_list[0]
            string_number_ck = str(number_ck)
            print("Corner Kick(s): ", string_number_ck)

        if choice == "home team":
            start_home = time.time()
            input()
            end_home = time.time()
        if choice == "away_team":
            start_away = time.time()
            input()
            end_away = time.time()
            elapsed_home = end_home - start_home
            elapsed_away = end_away - start_away

        elif choice == "q":
            print(elapsed_away)
            print(elapsed_home)

body()
```

This doesn't work, but this is an idea of what I've got. If you didn't understand what I mean, please comment below so I can explain in more detail.

Comment: The code you've got there lets the user pick one of `'fk'`, `'ck'`, `'home team'`, `'away_team'`, or `'q'` each time it runs. It doesn't loop, so nothing's going to be kept between runs. Is that what you intended? There's other problems, but the fixes depend on that answer.

Comment: no i want it to loop, my program is bigger with more stats but this is just a preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this one

```
elapsed_home = 0
elapsed_away = 0
start_home = 0
start_away = 0
ball_home = False
ball_away = True # Assumimg that away team has the starting kick


def body():
    global elapsed_home, elapsed_away, start_home, start_away, ball_home, ball_away
    while True:
       choice = input("")
       ...
       ...
       if choice == "home team":
           if ball_home:
              continue:
           else:
              ball_away = False
              ball_home = True
              start_home = time.time()
              elapsed_away += time.time() - start_away
              print "away elapsed: " + str(elapsed_away)

       if choice == "away_team":
            if ball_away:
                continue
            else:
                ball_away = True
                ball_home = False
                start_away = time.time()
                elapsed_home += time.time() - start_home
                print "home elapsed: " + str(elapsed_home)
       ...
 # Initialize depending on who has the starting kick
 if ball_away:
     start_away = time.time()
 else:
     home_start = time.time()
 body()
```

Comment: i didn't understand everything that you just said but i will get back to you when i research a little bit more on threading

Comment: this works but i think it has a mistake while counting because when i format it so it prints the percentage it always shows that away is 100% but home is 0% 


`total_num = elapsed_home + elapsed_away
perc_num = 100 / total_num
final_home = elapsed_home * perc_num
final_away = elapsed_away * perc_num
print(final_home)
print(final_away)
round_home = round(final_home, 1)
round_away = round(final_away, 1)
string_home = str(round_home)
string_away = str(round_away)
print_home = string_home + "%"
print_away = string_away + "%"
print(print_home)
print(print_away) `

Comment: for some reason it doesn't format it as code with backticks

Comment: also where do i put ` if ball_away:
     start_away = time.time()
 else:
     start_home = time.time() `

Comment: This if is not a part of the body() function. You should place it just before calling body()

Comment: you are a god @finmor it worked... now what is left is to sell your code...Kappa

Comment: I'm glad I've helped. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

Given that (as you said in comments) that code is called repeatedly in loops, you have two issues.

- `elapsed_home` is being set in the `'away_team'` branch instead of the `'home_team'` branch. Simple enough to fix, just move that up a few lines.
- All of your variables are declared inside the function - which means they don't exist outside of it, and they don't persist between calls. You have three (reasonable) options to fix this:

  1. Declare them all globally (at the top of the function, put e.g. `global elapsed_home`.
  2. Pass them all in as arguments every time. Return them all every time.
  3. Use a class to hold them, make it a method on that class instead of a function.

Take your pick.

Comment: well yes that worked but it didn't answer my main question: while its recording time i can not record ck nor fk. I would have to hit enter and then. What i want is when i type the away team, the clock for the home team ends and the clock for the away starts but if for example while home has the ball and gets a free kick i want it to count time without stopping it and then record the stat